# Using Mac Mini to store a Bootable Backup of Mac via SSH

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, backup, ssh, rsync

I'm trying to back up my Macbook since I'm going to be traveling around for the next 2 weeks.

My plan is to use rsync and SSH keys to backup a bootable copy of the Snow Leopard Macbook to a MacMini at my house running Tiger.  This way, my PC will be automatically backing up to the Mac Mini at home as I travel around.

I have set up a script to try to perform this, it looks like this :

```
#! /bin/bash

if (( `id -u` != 0 )); then
{ echo "Sorry must be root"; exit; }
fi;

ssh-add
ssh root@machine.at.home "/usr/sbin/vsdbutil -d /Volumes/BackupDrive" /usr/local/bin/rsync -aNHAXxv --protect-args --exclude-from backup_excludes --fileflags --delete --force-change --rsync-path="/usr/local/bin/rsync" / root@machine.at.home:/Volumes/BackupDrive >> ~/Library/Logs/rsync.log
ssh root@machine.at.home "bless -folder /Volumes/BackupDrive/System/Library/CoreServices"
```

This script works great for the backup, but when I try to boot from it, it displays a grey Apple screen with a spinning flash wheel, and doesn't boot.

When I connect the hard disk directly to the machine and run this :

```
/usr/local/bin/rsync -aNHAXxv --protect-args --exclude-from backup_excludes --fileflags --delete --force-change --rsync-path="/usr/local/bin/rsync" / /Volumes/Rsync >> ~/Library/Logs/rsync-hd.log
sudo bless -folder /Volumes/Rsync/System/Library/CoreServices
```

It works fine, and boots from the drive.

Any ideas on how I could get this to work?

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Jay

Answer (score 4):

You could try [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/). When using it to backup to a remote machine, it does rsync over ssh with pre-shared keys and does make bootable backups.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.jwz.org/doc/backups.html

Should cover you.